# Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Integer` in a Query

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I fall on a incomprehensible bug with my query !

HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Integer` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.

Decidedly I would not have thought to have so much difficulty with my queries in Java ... I just want to take all OrderProduct List by User using a query with Integer. I hope it will be my last question about Java queries :p

My OrderProduct Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth/orders")
@CrossOrigin()
public class OrderController {

    ProductService productService;
    OrderService orderService;
    OrderProductService orderProductService;
    UserService userService;
    OrderProductRepository orderProductRepository;

    public OrderController(ProductService productService, 
            OrderService orderService, 
            OrderProductService orderProductService,
            OrderProductRepository orderProductRepository
            ) {
        this.productService = productService;
        this.orderService = orderService;
        this.orderProductService = orderProductService;
        this.orderProductRepository = orderProductRepository;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/getListUserOrder")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<OrderProduct> getUserOrderList(@RequestBody Integer id){
        return orderProductRepository.findOrderProductByUser(id);
    }
```

My OrderProductRepository

```
    @Query("SELECT o FROM OrderProduct o WHERE o.user=:id")
    public Iterable<OrderProduct> findOrderProductByUser(
      @Param("id") Integer id);

}
```

My OrderProduct Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="OrderProduct")
public class OrderProduct {

    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonIgnore
    private OrderProductPK pk;

    @Column(name="QUANTITY", nullable = false) private Integer quantity;
    
    @Column(name="USER", nullable = false) private Integer user;

    @Column(name="ORDERING_DATE", nullable = true) private Date dateOrdering;
    
    @Column(name="DELIVER_DATE", nullable = true) private Date dateDeliver;
    
    private boolean active;



    public OrderProduct() {
        super();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you need to replace in your controller definition of get method to this:

```
@GetMapping("/getListUserOrder")
public @ResponseBody Iterable<OrderProduct> getUserOrderList(@RequestParam Integer id) {
    return orderProductRepository.findOrderProductByUser(id);
}
```

In your variant (with **@RequestBody** annotation on id parameter) you need specify user id in body in json format (just specify value with id in request body) and this is probably not what you want.
My variant (with **@RequestParam** annotation on id parameter) accepts the given parameter via request parameter, for example /api/auth/orders/getListUserOrder?id=5. And this is a more appropriate way for the GET method.

Comment: Ok it was the good answer ! By angular I throw the id with the url and RequestParam allows to deal with it into my springboot app ! Tahnk you a lot  ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `id` as a **@RequestBody**, but what you are passing is not a valid **JSON**.

It must be as follows:

```
"your_id_here"
```

or just:

```
your_id_here
```

**Instead** of using a request body(since you have just an `id`, a single parameter), it would more convenient using `@RequestParam`